# JSP is displayed as text when jstl tags are included

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have a project with following code:

Starter:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Starter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Starter.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Starter.class, args);
}
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {
@RequestMapping(value = "greeting", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =    "text/html; charset=UTF-8")
public ModelAndView greeting() {
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("Greeting");
    return modelAndView;
}
}
```

Configuration:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hello"})
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
}

@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    bean.setViewClass(org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView.class);
    bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/");
    bean.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return bean;
}

}
```

JSP (Greeting.jsp):

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<body>
<h1>Spring MVC Hello World Annotation Example</h1>

<h2>HELLO !</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

POM: dependencies to springboot and jstl:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I sent a request to http://localhost:8080/greeting I recieved in webbrowser a file Greeting.jsp as a text file (file didn't executed). When I remove from Greeting.jsp following lines:

```
<%@ page session="false" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

request is processed correctly - browser shows only text from header tags ("Hello" and "Spring MVC...").

The question is: whats wrong with JSTL view configuration ?